# How do you do to keep useless datas with good performance?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Environment : SQL Server 2005, Windows Server 2003

The system in question is an online booking system. In it, you can create special offers.

A special offer has some period of validity.

We keep in our database every period entered by our client even if the period is in the past. We have to keep these periods.

The system exists since 10 years so most of the periods in the database are past.

The problem :

- to select the periods for a special offer is very long
- I select special offers with no valid period associated, so I have to select my offers , then my periods, and after that I remove the offers that doesn't have any valid period.

How do you manage that kind of case ? Is there any built-in tool to ignore a part of the data in some case ?

Comment: "select the periods for a special offer is very long " - suitable indexes....?

Comment: Ok, let's say I have a column DateBegin and DateEnd for a period, what do you call a "suitable indexes".

Comment: depends on your actual queries...

Comment: What is long? How many rows does your table contain? Do you *have* indexes?

Comment: OK ... so I create an index containing every field in my where clause ?

Comment: I have an index containing the DateBegin and DateEnd field, what takes long is : select the offers and then select the periods. Select the offers is long because I select a lot of offers for nothing (they have no periods), and select the periods is long because 90% percent of them are past.

Comment: @Remi, you haven't answered how many rows there are and you should definitly show us the query. Right now, we are shooting blind.

Comment: Starting to wonder if this has any programming related content....

Comment: I don't understand your behaviour, just asking for ideas or leads, and you're like you just want to prove that I'm stupid... I can't show my request because you wouldn't understand it : most of my tables/ column are named in french.

Comment: @Remi, I don't know if you are offended by my comment or Mitch's but if you are, I think it's safe to say that that most certainly was not our intention. The fact remains though that I am convinced we would be of better service if you told us about how much data we are talking about and showed us the query. Never mind if the table names are french, SQL is SQL. Perhaps the query could be restructured without anyone requiring any domain knowledge about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can speed up things by adding the right indexes, but if that doesn't help (enough) you can think about creating a second table to archive the past offers in. That way, you won't be bothered by the old data, but if you need it (for reports or other reasons) you can still refer to the archive.

Comment: Do you have any advice about "the right indexes" ? Let's say I filter my periods on 10 fields, I have to create an index for every field ? containing every field ?

Comment: That depends on how your queries are built up. It can be beneficial to have queries on each column as well as on a combination of columns. I can't tell from here, but a simple example: If you got columns A, B and C, and you query for a combination of A and C, you should create an index on column A and C combined. If you create an index on A, B and C combined (with B being the second column), that index will only be usable for the A part if you filter on A and C.

Comment: You may not need indices on every column, but at least on the combination(s) of columns that result in only a relatively small subset of rows. In those rows the database can do a full scan to filter the rest of the result. I can't say which columns exactly, because it would need me to look at your table, your queries and their explain plans and your data to make an educated guess, and might still need some experimenting after that.

Comment: Ok I see, I'll improve my index I think because I have only one on  all the filtered columns, maybe only on the date would be better.